# Does MariaDB disconnect automatically or Should i have to disconnect Manually?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I got to use MariaDB for my University Project.
it's my first time doing it, so I dont't know well how to use and code JDBC Driver and mariaDB.
Now I'm implementing the code in many places while looking at examples.
As I see, All the examples seems to creating Statement and making connection by using "DriverManager.getConnection"

Now I have a question.
I'm going to create a DBmanager Class that can connect, create tables, execute queries, and execute the code that updates data on tables in a single line.

I thought all the examples would run alone in one method and came from different places, so I could only try a new connection and create a code that would not close. But I have a gut feeling that this will be a problem.

Is there any way I can leave a connection connected at a single connection to send a command, and disconnect it to `DB.disconnect()`? And I'd appreciate it if you could tell me whether what I'm thinking is right or wrong.

The code below is the code I've written so far.

- I am sorry if you find my English difficult to read or understand. I am Using translator, So, my English could not be display as I intended.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;
public class DBManager {
    /*********INNITIAL DEFINES********/
    final static private String HOST="sumewhere.azure.com";//Azure DB URL
    final static private String USER="id@somewhere";//root ID
    final static private String PW="*****";//Server Password
    final static private String DRIVER="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";//DB Driver info

    private String database="user";


    /***************API***************/

    void setDB(String databaseinfo){
        database=databaseinfo;
    }

    private void checkDriver() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("MariaDB JDBC driver NOT detected in library path.", e);
        }
        System.out.println("MariaDB JDBC driver detected in library path.");
    }

    public void checkOnline(String databaseinfo) throws Exception
    {
        setDB(databaseinfo);
        this.checkDriver();
        Connection connection = null;
        try
        {
            String url = String.format("jdbc:mariadb://%s/%s", HOST, database);

            // Set connection properties.
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("user", USER);
            properties.setProperty("password", PW);
            properties.setProperty("useSSL", "true");
            properties.setProperty("verifyServerCertificate", "true");
            properties.setProperty("requireSSL", "false");

            // get connection
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            throw new SQLException("Failed to create connection to database.", e);
        }
        if (connection != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Successfully created connection to database.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Failed to create connection to database.");
        }
        System.out.println("Execution finished.");
    }

    void makeCcnnection() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        // Check DB driver Exists
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("MariaDB JDBC driver NOT detected in library path.", e);
        }
        System.out.println("MariaDB JDBC driver detected in library path.");
        Connection connection = null;
    }

    public void updateTable(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DBManager DB = new DBManager();
        DB.checkOnline("DB");
    }
}
```

Comment: Include the connection close in a `finally` block. That pattern becomes really important when the app scales up to using a connection pool, so connections get returned to the pool.  On the MariaDB side, the server will terminate abandoned connections when `wait_timeout` or `interactive_timeout` expires. Our design goal should be this feature is an extra backstop, handling connections abandoned by a crashed JVM. Apps running in the JVM should be explicitly closing connections, not abandoning them. (With a connection pool, app "open" and "close" connection will be "borrow: and "return"

Answer (score 1):

For a studying project it's okay to give a connection from your DB Manager to client code and close it there automatically using [`try-with-resources` construction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Maybe you will find it possible to check Connection Pool tools and apply it further in your project or use as example (like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), here is a [good introduction](https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp)).

Answer (score 0):

Read about **Java try with resources**. I think that this link could be usefull for your problem.
[JDBC with try with resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465572/jdbc-with-try-with-resources)